# Loading an external script before loading components - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue project, I would like to load a script from a server (e. g. `https://myurl.com/API.js`). 
The script contains a variable, which I would like to use in my Vue component (view).
The problem is that when I load that scrip using the loadScript module:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';

Vue.use(LoadScript);
Vue.loadScript('https://quvia.cz:4443/portalAPI.js')
```

It is then loaded after the Vue component, so when try to `console.log(externalScriptVariable)`, it is undefined. If I would setTimeout for 1 second, it would output the variable just fine.

What can I do in Vue.js to *"await"* the script loading, so it would load before every other Vue component?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async/await`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';

Vue.use(LoadScript);

(async function() {
  await Vue.loadScript('https://quvia.cz:4443/portalAPI.js');
  // other things after script loaded
})();
```

Or promise's `then`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';

Vue.use(LoadScript);

Vue.loadScript('https://quvia.cz:4443/portalAPI.js').then(() => {
  // other things after script loaded
})
.catch(() => {
  // error
});
```

Comment: I can't do that, because all the `import` statements in main.js have to be top-level, that means that they can't be in an async function or .then .

Comment: @Wayne How do you call a method from the external script?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the `beforeCreate()` lifecycle that vue provides and load the script from there.

```
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';

export default {
  name: "App",
  beforeCreate() {
    LoadScript('https://quvia.cz:4443/portalAPI.js')
  }
};
```

there are also other lifecycles that might suit your needs which  you can find here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Also, calling the `LoadScript` this in the main.js would make sure it is done before any components load

Comment: That's strange, because I was calling the LoadScript in main.js, but the problem still existed.
Here is my main.js file (link to Google Drive): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cruKTZ606QsDIrD_74HY-FQi86nldCK5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried using the beforeCreate lifecycle? I think that will be the solution to your problem. You can use the beforeCreate on the app.vue (or your starting component) so that it will available before all other components are loaded

Comment: @Jochem How do you call a method from the external script?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problems were resolved by the "window" scope. Also, if you need to access any Vue element inside the "onload" function, you need a new variable for the "this" instance.

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
      name: "Payment",
      methods: {
        ...mapActions(["aVueAction"])
      },
      created() {
            let paywayScript = document.createElement("script");
            let self = this;
            paywayScript.onload = () => {
              // call to Vuex action.
              self.aVueAction();
              // call to script function
              window.payway.aScriptFunction();
            };
            // paywayScript.async = true;
            paywayScript.setAttribute(
              "src",
              "https://api.payway.com.au/rest/v1/payway.js"
            );
            document.body.appendChild(paywayScript);
      }
};
</script>
```

I worked with this on Vue 2.6.